# Jquery is not working in Rails 3.2.8

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my name is Pamela and i'm new to this version of rails, i'm trying to put some validations and datepickers in a form, but for some reason the jquery is not working, i've searched a lot and tried several things but they didn't work. 
Here's my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker-es
//= require jquery.validate
//= require messages_es
```

This is my application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I ran: rails generate jquery:install and this is the result:

deprecated  You are using Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline enabled, so this generator is not needed.
              The necessary files are already in your asset pipeline.
              Just add `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js
              If you upgraded your app from Rails 3.0 and still have jquery.js, rails.js, or jquery_ujs.js in your javascripts, be sure to remove them.
              If you do not want the asset pipeline enabled, you may turn it off in application.rb and re-run this generator.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Updated:

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@contrato) do |f| %>
  <% if @contrato.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@contrato.errors.count, "error") %> no han permitido que el contrato sea guardado:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @contrato.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><font color="red"><%= msg %></font></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Obra' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_nombre_obra %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label 'Nombre Contratista/Empresa' %><br />
   <%= f.select :contratista_id, Contratista.find(:all, :order => "empresa").collect{|c| [c.empresa, c.id] } %>
  </div> 
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Municipio' %><br />
    <%#= f.number_field :tipo_norma_legal_id %>
    <%= f.select :municipio_id, Municipio.find(:all, :order => "nombre").collect{|c| [c.nombre, c.id] } %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Localidad' %><br />
    <%#= f.number_field :tipo_norma_legal_id %>
    <%= f.select :localidad_id, Localidad.find(:all, :order => "nombre").collect{|c| [c.nombre, c.id] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Tipo de Norma Legal' %><br />
    <%#= f.number_field :tipo_norma_legal_id %>
    <%= f.select :tipo_norma_legal_id, TipoNormaLegal.find(:all, :order => "tipo_norma_legal_descripcion").collect{|c| [c.tipo_norma_legal_descripcion, c.id] } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Nº Norma Legal '%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_nro_norma_legal %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Año Norma Legal' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_anio_norma_legal %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Nº de Expediente (solo numeros)' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_expte %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Fecha del Contrato' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_fecha %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Monto de Contrato ($)' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_monto %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Plazo de Obra (dias)' %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :contrato_plazo_obra %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Contrato Finalizado' %>
    <%= f.check_box :finalizado %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <br class="clearfix" />
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar', :class=>'button' %>
  </div>

<% end %>


<%= render(:partial => "javascripts") %>
```

This is the partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#new_contrato").validate({

        rules: {
        "contrato[contrato_nombre_obra]": {required: true, minlength: 3 , maxlength: 60 },
        "contrato[contrato_monto]": {digits: true},
        "contrato[contrato_plazo_obra]": {required: true, digits: true}
        "contrato[contrato_contrato_expte]": {digits: true}
        }
      });
    // Datepicker
        $('#contrato_contrato_fecha').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
        });


});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show what the error is and the snippet of your code?

Comment: Are there are any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: NO, that's the strange thing, couldn't find any javascripts errors

Answer (score 0):

You should already have access to jQuery and Unobtrusive jQuery if you have generated the application and haven't changed the gemfile. Check if it includes jquery-rails. If it does, then you already have jquery ready to use. You don't need to `run rails generate jquery:install`.

Comment: yes, i also thought the same thing, i really don't why is not validating the form or showing the datepickers. Is such a mistery, and i really need the javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, thank you very much for helping me... i've tried another one last thing... i started from fresh, i've realized that maybe i deleted something in my effort to make javascript work, so i decided to created a the project again (not the ideal thing to do, right?), so i just copied my views in the new project, made the migrations, etc... And now at least the validations are working, i didn't try datepickers or other stuff yet (hopefully they'll work too). If ever know what happened, i'll let you know it may help someone else.